# Can someone explain this Java code to me? (beginner in Java)

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

This is from the book "Java: A beginner's Guide". Chapter #3: While loops. I want to know how these to loops work together in the following program.

```
// Compute integer power of 2.
public class Power {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int e, result;

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            result = 1;
            e = i;
            while(e > 0) {
                result = result * 2;
                e--;
            }

            System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html      Read the book and then you will know.

Comment: If you got the code from the book then there must be explaination in the book as well.

Comment: Begin by understanding what the code does without the outer loop, then check the relationship between the loops.

Comment: I suggest to use either a pen and paper or a debugger and run through the code.

Comment: The explanation is very brief.

Comment: I do know how the two loops work separately. I just want to know how do they work when they interact with each other specially in this program.

Comment: I have commented each line of code for you

Comment: @GhulamMuhammad what do you mean, "when they interact with each other?"  What kind of interaction are you expecting?  The inner loop does what it does e times.  The outer loop does what it does (including the inner loop) ten times.  The variable e, controls the inner loop is set equal to the variable i on each trip around the outer loop.  What else is there to know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Compute integer power of 2.

    //Declare two primitive variables named 'e' and 'result' of type 'int' with no current 'value'
    int e, result;

    /*
     * Basic for-loop:
     * Instantiate an int named 'i' with 'value' 0
     * Set condition, until i(currently 0) is < 10 continue looping
     * After each loop, increment i by 1(i++), therefore i = i+1 after each loop
     */
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        result = 1; //Global variable 'result' is now with value 1
        e = i; //Global variable 'e' is now with value 1
        while(e > 0) { //Whilst the 'e' variable is > 0
            result = result * 2; //Multiply result(currently 1) by 2
            e--; //Decrement 'e' by 1 (e--) therefore 'e' is now e = e-1 after each loop
        }
        System.out.println("2 to the " + i + " power is " + result);
    }
```

---

This prints:

```
2 to the 0 power is 1
2 to the 1 power is 2
2 to the 2 power is 4
2 to the 3 power is 8
2 to the 4 power is 16
2 to the 5 power is 32
2 to the 6 power is 64
2 to the 7 power is 128
2 to the 8 power is 256
2 to the 9 power is 512
```

Comment: Thank you too for this extremely helpful reply. Will upvote this once I accumulate enough positive rep.

Comment: No worries, feel free to mark it as the answer if you feel it satisfies your question

Comment: Just one more question. Why the result is 2^i?

Comment: Because i is the variable inside your loop that changes. As soon as the loop starts i is equal to 0, after a loop ends, i is then equal to 1, this will go on till i is then equal to the value of 10 which is why we set i < 10. That is our condition

Comment: Just figured it out myself. Stupid me. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop contains the `while` loop (it is inside the brackets).

Every time the outer loop is executed (i.e. for `i` taking values `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`... `9`), the inner loop is executed with `e` taking values `i`, `i-1`, `i-2`, `i-3`... `1`, and `result` taking values `1`, `2`, `4`, `8`, ... `2^i`.

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful reply. Can't up vote you as I haven't accumulated enough positive reputation.

Comment: Why the result is getting 2^i?

Answer (score 1):

**First Step value:**

```
i=0, result=1, e=0
```

Now While loop will start condition 0>0: "FALSE"

Output is: 2 to the 0(i.e value of i) power is 1(i.e value of result)

**Second Step Value:**

```
i=1,result=1,e=1
```

At while loop condition 1>0 : "TRUE"

```
result=1*2; e=0;
```

Again condition check 0>0 : "FALSE"

so, Output is: 2 to the 1(i.e value of i) power is 2(i.e value of result)

similarly output will be like:

2 to the 2 power is 4

2 to the 3 power is 8

.....................

.....................

2 to the 9 power is 512.